# How to find the maximum value for given range in a big data set?

Tags: r

I have a big dataset I named Jon that looks like this:

[image]

and i have another file that i named "test" that has the start and end coordinates that I want to look at in the Jon file.

[image]

Based on this information, can you help me write a code that will give me the biggest lgmeandiff information for each of the coordinates that lies in the test file for each row.
For example: `test[c(3),]`, the coordinates are between 358-366. SO I want to look at these coordinates values in the Jon file and choose the row that has the biggest lgmeandiff for that range and write that information to an output file for each of coordinates.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(test)){
  listofcats <- seq.int(test$from[i], test$to[i])
}

tempframe <- c()
outputframe <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = ncol(Jon)))

for(i in 1:nrow(test)){
  for(k in 1:nrow(Jon)){
      tempframe <- seq.int(test$from[i], test$to[i])
      tempMax <- Jon[c(max(abs(Jon$lgmeandiff[k] %in% tempframe))),]
      outputframe <- rbind(tempframe,outputframe)
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:

Data are too large, so I am including the dput(head()) for each data set:

for Jon dataset;

```
    structure(list(TTS = c(291L, 322L, 358L, 360L, 361L, 363L), lgmeandiff = c(-922337203685478, 
    -922337203685478, -0.0954, -0.9885, -1.4739, -3.7959), lgtotdiff = c(-922337203685478, 
    -922337203685478, 3.2265, 2.3334, 1.848, -0.4739), meandiff = c(0, 
    0, 0.936, 0.504, 0.36, 0.072), totdiff = c(0, 0, 9.36, 5.04, 
    3.6, 0.72), premean = c(0, 0.720000028610229, 1.15200004577637, 
    1.44000005722046, 1.58400001525879, 1.87200012207031), precnt = c(0, 
    7.20000028610229, 11.5200004577637, 14.4000005722046, 15.840000629425, 
    18.720000743866), sufmean = c(0, 0.720000028610229, 2.08800010681152, 
    1.94400005340576, 1.94400005340576, 1.94400005340576), sufcnt = c(0, 
    7.20000028610229, 20.8800008296967, 19.4400007724762, 19.4400007724762, 
    19.4400007724762)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

for test dataset

```
structure(list(from = c(291, 322, 358, 371, 392, 395), to = c(291L, 
322L, 366L, 382L, 392L, 401L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 
10L, 11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput()` (e.g. `dput(Jon)`) on both of those datasets instead of posting screenshots. If the data is too large, use `dput(head(Jon))`

Comment: Values in `test` refer to row numbers in `Jon`, not `Jon$TTS` ?

Comment: I think this might work (I'm assuming the `from` and `to` are row numbers, rather than values of over variables like `Jon$TTS`)?  `pmap(structure, \(from, to) {max(Jon$lgmeandiff[from:to])})`

Comment: What kind of output file?

Comment: Values in test refer to the numbers in Jon$TTS, not the row numbers. Let's say for the first row in test, we have 291, which is also in the first row of Jon. Whichever the row is found in the Jon$TTS

Answer (score 4):

[`join_by`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html) was added in `dplyr` 1.1.0 to create a join specification. In your case you want to merge if `TSS` falls `between` `from` and `to` (inclusive):

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(jon, test, by = join_by(between(TTS, from, to))) |>
  slice_max(lgmeandiff, by = c(from, to)) |>
  select(from, to, lgmeandiff)
```

**Output**

```
  from  to    lgmeandiff
1  291 291 -9.223372e+14
2  322 322 -9.223372e+14
3  358 366 -9.540000e-02
4  371 382            NA
5  392 392            NA
6  395 401            NA
```

---

Here is one option to write the output to an Excel file, where each coordinate pair will be a sheet in the workbook:

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(jon, test, by = join_by(between(TTS, from, to))) |>
  slice_max(lgmeandiff, by = c(from, to)) |>
  mutate(coord = paste(from, "-", to),
         lgmeandiff = lgmeandiff, .keep = "none") |>
  split(~ coord) |>
  writexl::write_xlsx("output.xlsx")
```

Note: Excel has a limit on the number of sheets. It is 255, so if you have more than 255 unique pairs (which is sounds like you might) then you might consider an alternate output type.

Answer (score 3):

A tidyverse solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my_func <- function(df, min, max) {
  df |> 
    filter(TTS >= min, TTS <= max) |> 
    pull(lgmeandiff) |> 
    max()
}

mutate(test, lgmeandiff = map2_dbl(from, to, ~ my_func(Jon, .x, .y)))

   from  to            lgmeandiff
1   291 291 -922337203685478.0000
2   322 322 -922337203685478.0000
3   358 366               -0.0954
7   371 382                  -Inf
10  392 392                  -Inf
11  395 401                  -Inf
```

The `-Inf` is only occurring because those specific ranges are not available in the rows of `Jon` provided.

@jay.sf's answer is likely a faster one to execute than mine, which should be of preference to you given the size of your dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Use `seq.int` in `Map`.

```
with(test, Map(seq.int, from, to)) |>
  {\(.) sapply(., \(i) max(jon[jon$TTS %in% i, 'lgmeandiff']))}() |>
  setNames(apply(test, 1, toString))
#      291, 291      322, 322      358, 366      371, 382      392, 392      395, 401 
# -9.223372e+14 -9.223372e+14 -9.540000e-02          -Inf          -Inf          -Inf 
# Warning messages:
# 1: In max(jon[jon$TTS %in% i, "lgmeandiff"]) :
#   no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
# 2: In max(jon[jon$TTS %in% i, "lgmeandiff"]) :
#   no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
# 3: In max(jon[jon$TTS %in% i, "lgmeandiff"]) :
#   no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

More verbose version without warnings:

```
with(test, Map(seq.int, from, to)) |>
  {\(.) sapply(., \(i) {
    v <- jon[jon$TTS %in% i, 'lgmeandiff']
    if (all(is.na(v))) {
      NA_real_
    } else {
      max(jon[jon$TTS %in% i, 'lgmeandiff'])
    }
  })}() |>
  setNames(apply(test, 1, toString))
#      291, 291      322, 322      358, 366      371, 382      392, 392      395, 401 
# -9.223372e+14 -9.223372e+14 -9.540000e-02            NA            NA            NA
```

You could also consider `max(., na.rm=TRUE)`.

---

*Data:*

```
jon <- structure(list(TTS = c(291L, 322L, 358L, 360L, 361L, 363L), lgmeandiff = c(-922337203685478, 
-922337203685478, -0.0954, -0.9885, -1.4739, -3.7959), lgtotdiff = c(-922337203685478, 
-922337203685478, 3.2265, 2.3334, 1.848, -0.4739), meandiff = c(0, 
0, 0.936, 0.504, 0.36, 0.072), totdiff = c(0, 0, 9.36, 5.04, 
3.6, 0.72), premean = c(0, 0.720000028610229, 1.15200004577637, 
1.44000005722046, 1.58400001525879, 1.87200012207031), precnt = c(0, 
7.20000028610229, 11.5200004577637, 14.4000005722046, 15.840000629425, 
18.720000743866), sufmean = c(0, 0.720000028610229, 2.08800010681152, 
1.94400005340576, 1.94400005340576, 1.94400005340576), sufcnt = c(0, 
7.20000028610229, 20.8800008296967, 19.4400007724762, 19.4400007724762, 
19.4400007724762)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

test <- structure(list(from = c(291, 322, 358, 371, 392, 395), to = c(291L, 
322L, 366L, 382L, 392L, 401L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 
10L, 11L), class = "data.frame")
```